# Reloading Forms With Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have PHP code that generates forms. I want to be able to reload a form with Ajax once the user clicks the submit button. This should reload the form the user was just typing on. I have this code:

PHP:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<form id="myform" method="post">  
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value=""/>  
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
HTML;

echo $html;
echo rand(1, 10);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery Form Example</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                name: "required",
            },
            messages: {
                name: "Please fill in answer.",
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
                $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    label.error { width: 250px; display: inline; color: red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results">
<?php require_once('process.php'); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, the whole page will reload after using it once. The only way I found to fix this is to put `<?php require_once('process.php'); ?>` outside the `<div id="results">` which causes two forms appear. Is there any way to fix this?
Also, I use this jquery plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Do you page have a javascript error ? What do you see in console ?

Comment: According to chrome, none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form looses it's EventListener upon replacing it with the new form you're getting from you PHP backend.

So you either have to re-initialize the plugin (by calling `$("#myform").validate({});` again after you get the new form from your AJAX post) or set the event listener to a parent DOM element (e.g. wrap you form in a `<div id="form-container">..</div>`) and replace the content of the container.

Try the following in your JS:

```
$("#results").on('submit', '#myform', function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please fill in answer.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });

    return false;

  });
```

**Edit:**
Just saw that you're using jQuery 1.4.2. To be able to use `on()` you would have to include at least jQuery 1.7, or use `live()`:

```
$("#results").live('#myform', 'submit', function(e) { //the rest of your stuff });
```

Comment: I mean they cause the page to reload every time.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer. You'll also have to add the normal return false and/or preventDefault() stuff....

Comment: Sorry, how stupid of me ^^ The plugin already adds it's own submit handler... you my proposal can't really work. Last thing you could try is to use `$("#results").validate({...});`. Could be that the plugin can handle this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34384/discussion-between-tom-and-mgrueter)

Answer (score 0):

use jqueryForm plugin. After this you can use ajaxSubmit.
[Jquery Form Plugin](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://malsup.com/jquery/form/&ei=f3v2UYywOeOR4ATTm4FY&usg=AFQjCNHnES7cM3L6bS9MpesfOJ3SPAKLeQ&sig2=6yu1uQ33Xz-QHW8V2wGBBw)

Comment: The submit button works for the first time with Ajax. Then it stops working. I don't think it's the plugin.